# Wordpress edited wp-config.php, now I can't login

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a site where I tried to fix some encoding issues by editing my wp-config.php file. The changes didn't help, so I changed it back again. Now, when I try to log in to admin, I get the dreaded "You do not have sufficient permissions" message. Unfortunately, I have no backup of the config but I am 100% sure that it looks like it did before.

I've tried this:
- Saving wp-config.php in different encodings
- Copying a fresh wp-config-sample.php, just adding my DB settings

I've found a lot of people on the web who have had this error after upgrading, migrating or for other reasons, but I haven't done one of these things, only edited the wp-config.php and then back again. There are solutions about repairing the DB, deleting plugins etc. but I'm afraid to try them in case WP decides to do some "magic" and take the whole site down. Besides, I can't see how the DB could get damaged just by editing the wp-config.php file.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Did you read this http://codex.wordpress.org/Login_Trouble ? Did you try to clear your browser cookies/cache ?

Comment: Yes, I've tried clearing cookies and cache, even tried repairing database and renaming the plugins folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We managed to solve it by copying all the info in the wp_user_roles row in the wp_options table in the database from another installation where everything worked. Now it works as it should.

A question: how can this value become screwed up by editing wp-config.php?

Comment: I suspect that the change in `wp-config` was simply a case of bad timing: something else was going on at/near the same time that was the real cause.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you've goofed your roles.

Note: **I'm assuming you're talking about Wordpress Single-Blog Mode, not Multi**

You can try this:

1. Set up a new database - with a different name
2. Rename your `wp-config.php` (so you don't have one)
3. Browse to your wordpress address

   - You will see the setup screen, go through the normal setup
   - You should be able to log in
4. Take a look at your *new* database's `wp_usermeta` table (the records for user #1) and compare that to your old database's `wp_usermeta` (records for user#1)
5. Make whatever changes are necessary in your old database to match the new one.
6. Edit your wp-config.php and switch the settings back to the old database